# Editor that can align and transform two images based on corresponding points

Tags: adobe-photoshop, alignment, overlay, photopea

Say I have one image A, and another B that is similar of the same perspective.  I want to pick corresponding points on each image, so that it can scale, rotate, and skew image B so that those points are at the same coordinates as the ones in image A.

I know that in video editing, there are features to tag corresponding points when overlaying shots, and this is what I would like to do but in image editing.

I also know that there are features like "auto align" layers that will do a similar task, but in my case this won't work because the images don't share the same background.

This is also a common feature in CAD programs, where you add a constraint to two points, and the rest of the object will adjust to correspond.  I need this to work on raster images though.

Are there any tools that do this?

Comment: Try at first Hugin. That program has been around since 2003. Originally it stitched together images by matching selected control points as you want now. That worked  with photos which were shot from the same place, but to different directions. Check if it still has that capability. I have used Photoshop after it learned to make acceptable panoramas.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve or what has failed?. It's hard to solve a problem like this without seeing anything,.

Comment: Two points is not enough to align two images with skew. But yes most image editors can roatete and translate images.

Comment: @kexxgem, thanks, but it is specifically for photos.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I have tried to do it manually by making one layer 50% transparent and then trying to transform it so they line up.

Comment: @joojaa I only said two points for the CAD example.  If select two points (each in a different object) and tell the program they are in the same location, the editor is able to adjust the objects so those two points coincide.  With two images, I would select several pairs of coinciding points.

Comment: If you want only to match images but not to blend them to one automatically and a shift + a linear transformation (rotate, scale X, scale Y) are enough you can use Cartesian transform. It's in G'MIC effect pack which is available for free for Photoshop, GIMP, Krita and Paint.NET. Calculating the transformation coefficients from coincident point coordinates needs some elementary engineering math skills. Cartesian transform can actually use as complex formulas as one can write with Python math expressions, but only shift+rotate+scale are easy to decide from coincidences.